# Chrome Extension - not sending cookies in the request

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've read tons of questions on SO, tried multiple things but to no luck. My question would be similar, but I'm posting because I've tried everything but still not succeeded.

I want to check whether there's a user session maintained at my server. I've a webservice which returns a boolean value, based on the cookies received.

It's the responsibility of the browser to send cookies (if any) while requesting the server. So, when I request via the chrome-extension, theoretically the browser should send along the cookies too. However, it does not.

Here's my code:-

**content.js**

```
fetch('https://zoffers.in/apis/shops/get_aff_url/', {
    credentials: 'include',
    mode: 'cors',
    async: false,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'Hubot',
        login: 'hubot',
    })
})
.then(function(data) {

})
.catch(function(error) {

})
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "https://*/*/"
        ],
        "js": ["js/content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        // "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Click here!"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "identity.email",
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "cookies",
        "https://zoffers.in/"
    ]
}
```

What wrong am I doing? Can anyone please help me through it.

**UPDATED**

**content.js**

```
message = {
    'event_type': 'Event1',
}
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        if(request.event_type === 'Event1'){
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
                fetch('https://zoffers.in/apis/shops/get_aff_url/', {
                    credentials: 'include',
                    mode: 'cors',
                    async: false,
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        name: 'Hubot',
                        login: 'hubot',
                    })
                })
                .then(function(data) {

                })
                .catch(function(error) {

                })
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Have added `background.js` to manifest.json file. But still not working.

Comment: Chrome deprecated cross-origin requests inside content scripts. Do it in the background script as shown in the [official CORB explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches).

Comment: Still doesnt help. Even after shifting the fetch code to background.js, the request still doesn't have the cookie headers.

Comment: Please check the updated code.

Comment: I tried logging with another user too, but no luck. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard [Cookies api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) and access cookies for any URL that is available.

Comment: How would I then set the cookie into the web request?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast That's another question. Btw have you tried 'credentials: "include"' ? https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/452#issuecomment-397155739

Comment: Yes. Check the question. Already tried with `credentials:include`. I researched on sending the cookie too, we've to use `webRequest` API. Thanks for the help.

Comment: However, I believe the problem is something else. It has something to do with cross-origin request. I'm making a request to DomainA while on DomainB website. This blocks the cookie to be sent automatically. I'm trying whether it could be sent automatically without explicitly passing cookies. I've found with `xhr.withCredentials = true;`, but it still doesn't work. Any lead to this would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the SameSite attribute of the cookies to None.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

You may also have to set your browser to accept third-party cookies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.